# What is the verb of "boldface"?

Tags: word-request

One can make a part of a text bold or write in in boldface. Do we have a verb for this? E.g., I have *bolded/boldfaced* 3 words in the following sentence:

> Currently, **margins are tight** and turnover is dependent on inclusive
>   tours and business travel respectively, with other services bringing
>   far smaller contribution.

Comment: Yes, you can use *bold* as a verb; it's completely unremarkable and I've seen it (used by native speakers) often on the internet (i.e., informally). Unfortunately, I can't find any dictionaries (barring Wiktionary) that support this. The formal and "official"-sounding word is *embolden*, but it might be a little too much for an informal conversation. Just to be safe, you can always use a verb like *make*, *highlight*, *mark*, etc., with *(in) bold* accompanying it.

Comment: 'embolden' makes it sound 'more brave' ;-) I think so long as we avoid 'bolderised' we're good to go.

Comment: I rarely see any verb used for this directly. It's more common to see "emphasize the text with boldface" or "set the word in bold."

Answer (score 1):

Informally, ***bolded*** is fine. People use that in casual conversation all the time.

For something formal, you'll need a phrase.

> **Put** that section **in bold**.
>   This section is **emphasised** with a **bold typeface**.

The second of these is more formal than the first.